# Booting problems with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1180571/

Here is the url I was told to paste by way of asking for help after Boot Repair failed to resolve my problem. That problem, quite simply, is that I cannot boot Ubuntu even though I installed it on a spare partition (close to 450 gigabytes).

Comment: All looks normal there, when you try to boot Ubuntu, does it give you an error or anything like that?

Comment: Your question is quite fuzzy. describe your status more please

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](http://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu/) it teaches you how to dual boot between ubuntu and windows 8